# Preastashop Category pages are not showing all the products associated to them

Tags: module, controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have created several categories on my store. But I got a problem that I can't figure out. Category Pages are not showing all the products associated to them. On some pages all the associated products are being shown. On some page some of the total products are there. And Some pages just don't show any product at all. What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All products are active ? Any pagination ? If you think it's an error, you could set `debug mode` to "true" in `config/defines.inc.php` and post the error message here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes all the products are active. I can search them. They just don't appear in category page.
I will do it now.

Comment: Can you explain it more briefly? I didn't get that.

Comment: I added it but I can't see any error there. What should I do now?

Comment: Does it show a text like "No Product in this category" ?

Comment: Did you use module Layered navigation block? If yes for try dissable it and then check..

Comment: Yes I'm using. I will check it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. It wirked. @AgnesTom

Comment: If you want to use this module, all you need is reindex this module, in configuration module page on the top you have four butons, to do this.

Comment: I thought my problem has been solved but it's still there. Any other solution that I can try?